# How do you download images to a device using canon 1200d?

Tags: canon

Using a canon 1200d how do you download images onto your phone/laptop/iPad etc... Taking a random guess do you have to use a USB cable to dowbload them onto your laptop and then onto your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Most folks would use an SD card reader on their computer--especially since many computers have a card reader slot built-in.  This keeps you from running down the camera battery to simply transfer files, and can often be a faster and more convenient way to download images than using a USB cable.

The other alternative, since the 1200D does not come with built-in wi-fi, would be to get a wi-fi capable SD card to use in the camera that can then connect to an app on a smartphone, which lets you transfer images directly from the card to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

"Unfortunately, although not unexpectedly for a camera at this price point, the 1200D doesn’t ship with Wi-fi functionality. It is, however, compatible with Eye-Fi memory cards and as such supports wireless transfer of images in conjunction with Canon’s smartphone and tablet app."

Read more at http://www.whatdigitalcamera.com/reviews/digital-slrs/canon-eos-1200d-review#hjIcGFyU4tQTI4pZ.99

---

Transfer them to your PC (I suggest using the EOS utility, it works fast - it came on the CD you got with your camera.) and then from your PC to your device, via USB - as you said.

Or you could try that Eye-fi, which I haven't used before.

Answer (score 0):

Canon 1200d package provides a USB wire, even though you didnt install canon's EOS PC SUITE on your PC, Windows will still read your camera's memory card. Also you can use a card reader. I would suggest you to use usb wire and install EOS SUITE in your pc because its has other advantages like canon editor(for post production) and photo viewer(for reading RAW(.cr2) images).